# form setstate on submit, not on onchange

Tags: reactjs

I have a view showing name and email. I click edit, and an overlay shows up. I want to have the state updated on save changes, not on change, as to avoid having this.state.name and this.state.newName...

Not sure how to handle this...

This is the view - not editable

```
<div>
   <span>{name}</span>
   <span>{email}</span>
</div>
```

This is the form - editable

```
<form>           
  <div>
     <span>
        <input
           type="text"
           name="name"
           title="Please fill out this field"
           required
           onBlur={event => { handleChange(event) }}
           onChange={event => { handleChange(event) }}
        />
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
     <span>
        <input
           type="text"
           name="email"
           title="Please fill out this field"
           required
           onBlur={event => { handleChange(event) }}
           onChange={event => { handleChange(event) }}
        />
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `onSubmit` goes on the form tag itself, so it would be like `<form onSubmit={() => doSomething()}>...<button type="submit"> Submit Me</button>`

Comment: right - but how can i update the values of name and email in the form to this.state.name and this.state.email with onSubmit

Comment: `<input value={this.state.name}>` Is that what you mean?

Comment: correct. i don't want to do this because one, it will prepopulate the form, and two, it will change the state of the view

Comment: `<input value={this.state.name && this.state.name}>`  will only fill in the field if the value is defined, so the first time it won't be. What do you mean by change the state of the view?

Comment: see the code in the original post - the view is showing this.state.name. the form is an overlay

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say, sorry

Comment: @Sam he displays on his page `name` and `email`. he wants to open a form to edit that state shown, but the page should only display `name` and `email` new values once the edit is done on submit click. otherwise, page would change `name` and `email` on typing.

Comment: @buzatto exactly! wondering if there is a way without maintaining two state values i.e. this.state.name & this.state.newName